# getting text values from a xml file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, appcelerator

I have this xml file that i want to get values from :

```
  <test> 
        <item>
            <question audio='audio/AB2001Q.mp3' category='Alertness'>Before you make a U-turn in the road, you should</question>
            <description audio='audio/s1,1.mp3'>If you want to make a U-turn, slow down and ensure that the road is clear in both directions. Make sure that the road is wide enough to carry out the manoeuvre safely.</description>
            <image ></image>
            <answers>
                <answer title='a' audio='audio/AB2001A.mp3'>give an arm signal as well as using your indicators</answer>
                <answer title='b' audio='audio/AB2001B.mp3'>signal so that other drivers can slow down for you</answer>
                <answer title='c' audio='audio/AB2001C.mp3'>look over your shoulder for a final check</answer>
                <answer title='d' audio='audio/AB2001D.mp3'>select a higher gear than normal</answer>
            </answers>
            <correctAnswers>
                <answer>c</answer>
            </correctAnswers>
        </item>
 </test>
```

How can I get the text content of question audio and the question text so for example

"audio/AB2001Q.mp3" is the question audio

"Before you make a U-turn in the road, you should" is the question text

this is what i have so far:

```
var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(blob);
var branch = doc.getElementsByTagName('item').item(0);
```

I am very new to xml!

Comment: Did you forget a `;` after `parseString(blob)` ?

Comment: sorry fix it i was using coffeescript thats why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similarly to what you'd do in HTML, e.g.:

```
var branch = doc.getElementsByTagName('item')[0];
var question = branch.getElementsByTagName('question')[0];
var q1Text = question.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var q1Audio = question.getAttribute['audio'];
```

(it would be a bit easier if you'd use jQuery, Sencha or any other library)

Comment: i would love to use jquery, but im not sure if could use it within titanium appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

After you got your Item you can use the `getAttribute('audio')` to get the information that attribute represents.
But bare in mind that if you have a large file containing many of these tags, that you might want to considure a different approach for getting the data.